# Opencart 2.1.0.2 remove IP from email invoices

Tags: php, email, ip, opencart2.x

How can I remove the IP from the email invoices sent to the customer when an order is placed or when the status of the order is changed in **Opencart 2.1.0.2**.

I have already removed `<b><?php echo $text_ip; ?></b> <?php echo $ip; ?><br /></td>` line from **catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl** file but it is still sending ip address.

Anyone plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following codes

`$data['text_ip'] = $language->get('text_new_ip');` in `catalog\model\checkout`

And

`$_['text_new_ip']= 'IP Address:';`in `catalog\language\english\mail`

And

`'ip'=> $order_query->row['ip'],` in`catalog\model\checkout\order.php`

Comment: remove this `'ip'=> $order_query->row['ip']`

Comment: it is also not working bro. Removed from **catalog\model\account\order.php** and **catalog\model\checkout\order.php**